# Web API Authentication using Message Handler and HttpClient

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am new to web development using Web API and I'm having some issues dealing with authentication using a custom message handler - specifically calling the Web API methods from a C# WPF application using HttpClient.

I've implemented authentication using a custom DelegatingHandler as in the TokenInspector class  example given [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630986/Cross-Platform-Authentication-With-ASP-NET-Web-API) (minus the HTTPS stuff). From the post I understand this moves authentication higher up in the request pipeline than having Action Filters as in [this](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) popular post.

I can successfully call my secured methods using an ajax call like the following (where _key is the security token):

```
$.ajax({
    url: _api + '/Item',
    beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("X-Token", _key);
                },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: fnSuccessResult,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               alert(xhr.status + ' ' + status + ' ' + error);
           }
});
```

I am in the process of writing a test harness for my Web API in C# - how do I handle this type of authentication in C# using HttpClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Headers.Add("X-Token", "token");
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: I am getting an "Internal Server Error" response, same as all my other attempts thus far. Is there a way to get the server to send more details on the error? I've put a breakpoint in the SendAsync method of my custom DelegatingHandler class, but it doesn't get hit.

Comment: How does your Handler look like? How did you register it?

Comment: Your code works as expected. There must be an error not related to your MessageHandler implementation.

Comment: I've added another method to my Controller to test - it works with your solution. I then changed the original controller method name after which it now works, strange... Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've added a similar [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880290/posting-data-to-web-api-using-custom-authentication) regarding problems I have posting data using this approach.