# Posting data to Web API using custom Authentication

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

This is a follow-up on an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836409/web-api-authentication-using-message-handler-and-httpclient) regarding using HttpClient with Web API performing authentication using a custom Message Handler.

I can request data from the server using the provided solution, but now I am having trouble posting JSON data to the server. Whenever I try posting data to the Web API I am returned an Internal Server Error response code.

Here is the code on the client side:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.Headers.Add("X-Token", UserSession.GlobalInstance.SecurityToken);
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    request.RequestUri = new Uri(_apiBaseAddress + "api/User");
    request.Content = new ObjectContent<UserDTO>(userDTO, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // handle result code
    }

    throw new Exception(String.Format("Server generated error response: {0}", response.StatusCode));
}
```

The declaration for the controller method:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public long Post(UserDTO userDTO)
    {
        // create user and return custom result
        // code (e.g. success, duplicate email, etc...)
    }
}
```

(I've also added [FromBody] to the method parameter, but end up with the same result).

A snapshot of the code for my message handler and routing configuration can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/RiaanDP/8194825).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected...

The server side.
Create a console application and run NuGet

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost`

`Program.cs`

```
internal class Program
{
    private static IDisposable _server;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _server = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:12345");
        Console.ReadLine();
        _server.Dispose();
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    } 
}
```

`WebApiConfig.cs`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var userTokenInspector = new UserTokenInspector {InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config)};
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "UserAuthenticationApi",
            "api/{controller}/Authenticate",
            new {controller = "User", action = "Authenticate"},
            null
            );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new {id = RouteParameter.Optional},
            null,
            userTokenInspector
            );
    }
}
```

`UserTokenInspector.cs`

```
public class UserTokenInspector : DelegatingHandler {
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        const string TOKEN_NAME = "X-Token";

        if (!request.Headers.Contains(TOKEN_NAME)) {
            return Task.FromResult(request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            "Request is missing authorization token."));
        }

        try {
            //var token = UserToken.Decrypt(request.Headers.GetValues(TOKEN_NAME).First());

            // validate token
            // ...
            // ...

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("alex"), new string[] { });
        }
        catch {
            return Task.FromResult(request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid token."));
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

`UserController.cs`

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public long Post(UserDTO userDTO)
    {
        // create user and return custom result
        // code (e.g. success, duplicate email, etc...)
        return 1;
    }
}
```

`UserDto.cs`

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

`ValuesController.cs`

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "yay");
    }
}
```

The Client... create a Console application and run NuGet:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`

`Program.cs`

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.Headers.Add("X-Token", "token");
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        var baseAddress = "http://localhost:12345/";
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(baseAddress + "api/User");
        var userDto = new UserDTO() {Username = "Alex"};
        request.Content = new ObjectContent<UserDTO>(userDto, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // handle result code
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```